# SVG Favicon does not refresh when Light/Dark Mode is changed

Tags: html, favicon

I am using a SVG favicon for light/dark mode with `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)` as described here: https://css-tricks.com/dark-mode-favicons/.

This works fine when I load the page. It also displays the favicon correctly when I manually change the dark mode and reload the page.

But when I manually change the dark mode and do not reload, the favicon is not updated.

Is that expected behavior?

Comment: Do you refresh the page after switching between dark and light mode?

Comment: @shilch After refreshing the page the favicon is updated. But I would like it to be automatically refreshed. I updated the question for clarification.

Comment: I assume that it's not a feature supported by the browser. What you could try is to programmatically replace the favicon link in the head of your document to one that contains the timestamp in a query parameter to force the browser to reload that icon. But I can not guarantee that it will work.

Comment: @shilch yeah that's a good idea. However it would be cool if browser would support it, because the same issue arises when you bookmark the site. And I cannot refresh favicon there with javascript.